# Omit Duplicate Only When In Sequential Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I've got a query returning the following information.  I used Over(PARTITION BY to include row numbers. I'm capturing every time my work_center_S begins a new Order#, but I want to exclude the beginning of a new order when the part_number was the same as the order/row previous to it.  I'm not able to use the DISTINCT function because a part_number may appear numerous times a day and I'll need to capture every time such a change occurs.

[![Query Return][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKvsR.jpg

```
+----+--------+---------------+-------------+------+
| rn | Order# | work_center_S | part_number | Hour |
+----+--------+---------------+-------------+------+
| 1  | 7098   | TB312         | 37203       | 1    |
+----+--------+---------------+-------------+------+
| 2  | 8797   | TB312         | 37194       | 4    |
+----+--------+---------------+-------------+------+
| 3  | 8802   | TB312         | 37355       | 11   |
+----+--------+---------------+-------------+------+
| 4  | 0946   | TB312         | 37194       | 15   |
+----+--------+---------------+-------------+------+
| 5  | 0698   | TB312         | 37203       | 18   |
+----+--------+---------------+-------------+------+
| 6  | 0699   | TB312         | 37203       | 21   |
+----+--------+---------------+-------------+------+
```

Comment: Please always specify the version of SQL Server you are using. `LAG`/`LEAD` might come in handy, for example, but not if you're using SQL Server 2000 (and we would have to guess).

Comment: I'm use SQL Server 2016.  I'm still trying to figure out how to get stackoverflow to display my return results properly.  If my query results are displayed it's rn 6 that shouldn't be there, because while rn 5 and rn 6 have a different Order# both Order# are for the same part_number.  As far as the business rules for this goes, the reason for this is, some work_center_S may only produce a single part_number, but they can't run off a single Order# indefinitely.  But a change in part_number is a significant event that I need to capture.

Comment: Well, that shouldn't be a code snippet for displaying simple tabular results, I think. See [advanced help for the editor](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume there isn't a `-1` part_number

```
select  Order#,work_center_S,part_number,Hour

from   (select  *
               ,lag(part_number,1,-1) over
                (
                    partition by  work_center_S
                    order by      Hour
                ) as prev_part_number

        from    mytable
        ) t

where   part_number <> prev_part_number
```

--

```
+--------+---------------+-------------+------+
| Order# | work_center_S | part_number | Hour |
+--------+---------------+-------------+------+
| 7098   | TB312         | 37203       | 1    |
+--------+---------------+-------------+------+
| 8797   | TB312         | 37194       | 4    |
+--------+---------------+-------------+------+
| 8802   | TB312         | 37355       | 11   |
+--------+---------------+-------------+------+
| 946    | TB312         | 37194       | 15   |
+--------+---------------+-------------+------+
| 698    | TB312         | 37203       | 18   |
+--------+---------------+-------------+------+
```

Comment: Hour might wrap around, maybe the `rm` column is the better choice to order by, but this is something OP must know.

Comment: @dlatikay, right but `rn` was generated by the OP for this post. The `rn` OVER clause should be used for the LAG function